# Replacing strings in a file containing ${Some string in variable} in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have text file which contains some keys of an hash table in the form of `${key}`. I need to parse the text file and replace `${key}` with it's value. Below is the code i am using

```
    #$config is the hashtable
   $document = Get-Content sample.txt
    foreach ($conf in $config.Keys) {
        [string]$match = '${' + $conf + '}'
        $document = $document.Replace($match, $($config.$conf))
        }
    }
```

I have tried below alternatives for `$match` string

`` [string]$match = "`${" + $conf + "}" ``

```
[string]$match='${'
$match+=$conf
$match+='}'
```

I even tried hard coding the string as `$match='${BACKUP_FOLDER}'` but in all the cases it does nothing. I have also tried `-match` to see if something matches but it always returns false.
I have confirmed that the text file contains several patterns of `${key}` format and if i copy the output of `$match` and search in the file i can find the patterns. Could you please point out what's wrong. I am using `Powershell V5.0`

Sample input

```
$config=@{"BACKUP_DIR"="_Backup";"STAGING_DIR"="_Staging"}
```

Contents of sample.txt

```
Overwrites the contents of new installation with old installation 
    Always use / as path seperator-->
    <!-- <rename path="" newName=""/> -->
    <!-- 
    ${BACKUP_DIR}
    rename-> rename file/directory in new installation
```

Output: `${BACKUP_DIR}` should be replaced with `_Backup`

Comment: Please edit the question and add sample input and desired output data.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there're a couple of typos in the hashtable. Following is a complete solution you can save as script and run, or copy to console.

```
$document = @'
Overwrites the contents of new installation with old installation 
    Always use / as path seperator-->
    <!-- <rename path="" newName=""/> -->
    <!-- 
    ${BACKUP_FOLDER}
    rename-> rename file/directory in new installation
'@

$config=@{"BACKUP_FOLDER"="_Backup";"STAGING_DIR"="_Staging"}

Write-Output "`n`nINPUT`n$document"

foreach ($conf in $config.Keys) {
        [string]$match = '${' + $conf + '}'
        $document = $document.Replace($match, $config.$conf)
}

Write-Output "`n`nOUTPUT`n$document"
```

Comment: Thanks @gms0ulman. Typo was just in the question. Your script works when i run it as standalone script but when i incorporate in my main script it's not working. Looks like the issue is something else. Some more head scratching to be done :(

Comment: @PramodAhanya To confirm; have you noticed the different 2nd argument in `.Replace`, `$config.$conf`?

Comment: sorry another typo in question. i am using `$config.$conf ` in the script.

Comment: @PramodAhanya `BACKUP_DIR` in hashtable and `BACKUP_FOLDER` in config also a typo?